# Unzip .gz file to create new line delimited json file - problems creating new line

Tags: python, json, gzip

I'm trying to unzip a gzip file so that I will just be left with a file containing many json files, each on its own line. However, when I try to append a new line '\n' after appending the json file, nothing happens. What's wrong with my code here?

```py
import gzip
import json

def load_file(file):
    if file.endswith('.gz'):
        with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as fff:
            file_content = fff.readlines()


    else:
        with open(file) as fileopen:
            file_content = fileopen.readlines()
    return file_content


loaded = load_file('9917-10137.gz')


x = []
for i in loaded:
    dictionary = json.loads(i)
    x.append(dictionary)
    x.append('\n')

print('x is',x)

with open('9917-10137convert.json', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(x))
```

The code just completely ignores the new line I'm trying to create, printing this gives me all my jsons on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that the JSON you write contains `[{"string": "value"}, "\n", {"string": "value"}, "\n", ...]` with alternating dictionaries and literal JSON-encoded newlines. To get what you seem to be looking for, simply write each dict followed by a literal (not JSON-enooded) newline.

```py
with open('9917-10137convert.json', 'w') as file:
    for i in loaded:
        file.write(i)
        file.write('\n')
```

This should produce a file of http://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score -1):

You should try using "`\\n`" instead of "`\n`", as `json.dumps()` encodes newlines by `\\n`, due to JSON standards.

So, probably changing this will solve your issue.

```
 x.append('\n')
```

More info:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders